# One view is over the other when added to dynamically generated relativelayout programatically

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, overlap

mDocView is overlapping the cramperView as if it's over the other. I want mDocView below topHeader.

**My cramper.xml-**

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backfromreport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_black_xml"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="goBack"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Messager"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

**Relevant Cramper Java file:**

```
private View cramperView;
private LinearLayout   topHeader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
topHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
private ReaderView   mDocView = new ReaderView(this); //ReaderView extends AdapterView
cramperView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cramper,null);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(cramperView);
layout.addView(mDocView);
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Is your ViewSwitcher in RelativeLayout ?

Comment: yes it is in RelativeLayout. Can you tell me that how to get my view below the linear layout header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said `ViewSwicher` is inside `RelativeLayout`, and you are using `layout.addView(mDocView)` after `layout.addView(cramperView)`, so it will always add `ReaderView`(which extends AdapterView) after your **cramper** layout.

**Solution is:**

Add `RelativeLayout` after `</ViewSwitcher>` in your xml file. Like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/docViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="1190dp"
        android:layout_height="1284dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In this `RelativeLayout` you can adjust width and height to make it fit for your layout.

Next step is to add your `ReaderView` in this `RelativeLayout` and as you are generating it dynamically you should add it in `onCreate()`.

```
     RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

     RelativeLayout docViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.docViewLayout);
     docViewLayout.addView(mDocView);

     layout.addView(cramperView);

     setContentView(layout);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add layout params for view's

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.linearLayout1); 
mDocView.setLayoutParams(rlp);

layout.addView(cramperView);
layout.addView(mDocView);
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: In the end I added `setContentView(rlp)` which is not working. Message - The method setContentView(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

Comment: You can't `setContentView` to Layout Parameters, only Layouts. Use `setContentView(yourParentLayout)`.

Comment: who told to add this setContentView(rlp) at last. look at my answer now.

Comment: cramperView is my whole xml file. If I place anything below it, not work. The result is same. I replaced `cramperView.getId()` with `topHeader.getId()` and `layout.addView(cramperView)` with `layout.addView(topHeader)` but it gave null pointer exception at `rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, topHeader.getId())`.

Comment: those things you have to take care about them. rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, topHeader.getId()) this will work if you want to add a view to below of topHeader view. just get layout and add those views to that view properly..

Comment: can you update your answer with what you commented out so that I will not get null pointer exception on `topHeader.getId()`.

Comment: that is a just ID for a view look at my answer now.

Comment: same result. My mDocView is coming over topHeader view, covering it completely.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the xml. ViewSwitcher is at top and we are adding cramperView to some dynamically generated layout.